# Connect 3 black wires to new switch

Tags: switch, wifi

I want to replace my old switch with a wifi switch. The old switch has only 3 wires attached, and in the box there is a bunch of white wires together and a copper wire capped off. The new wifi switch, is looking for a load, line, neutral and ground. How do I get convert the old wires to the new ones? Attached is the old switch box[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line wires are the two black wires going into the bottom of your old switch. Cut, strip and connect those to the line wire from your smart switch with a wire nut. The load wire is the one going into the top of your old switch. Remove it and connect it to the load wire from your smart switch with a wire nut. The white wire from your smart switch gets connected to the group of white wires with the red wire nut. The green wire from your smart switch gets connected to the caped copper wire in the box.

Comment: JACK, you Nailed it!  +   The guy is lucky this isn't a switch loop.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Ya gotta love the feed going to the switch instead of to the ceiling.